# Synchronization of Queues

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, queue

In my program I have a "Sender" and "Receiver" Thread, both of which act on one queue.

I have defined my queue in the class as:

```
static Queue<my_class> queue = new LinkedList<my_class>();
```

However, I think I am encountering problems because my `Queues` aren't synchronized. In my "Receiver" thread, I sometimes have to remove items from the Queue which will affect how the "Sender" Thread operates.

I was reading about `BlockingQueues` and was wondering whether that was what I need to use in my situation? If so, how do I change my declaration? Do I also need to declare the `BlockingQueue` in both the "Sender" and "Receiver" threads?

Would the `BlockingQueue` ensure that only one thread accessed the queue at any given time?

Sorry, I am quite new to the concept of synchronization and I find it quite confusing..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please read [Queue Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html).

Comment: `BlockingQueue` is an interface; if you don't need any other methods than what `Queue` already provides (note that `BlockingQueue` extends `Queue`), then you can just initialize your `Queue` with a thread safe version, for instance `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: " In my "Receiver" thread, I sometimes have to remove items from the Queue which will affect how the "Sender" Thread operates." <-- can you elaborate?

Comment: @fge In my "Sender" thread I update a variable based on the 1st item in the queue. So after the "Receiver" thread removes values from the queue, the "Sender" thread should correctly use the 1st item in the queue to update this variable. Thanks.

Comment: @Giri and what variable is that? Is the value of this variable actually dependent on the first item in the queue at any point in time?

Comment: @fge Sorry for the late reply. The variable that the "Sender" updates is an acknowledgment number which in turn the "Receiver" requires. However, I found that this is not the only issue. In my "Sender", I have an `If` statement to check whether the `queue` is NOT empty. However, SOMETIMES, it will enter this `if` condition and then return a `NULL POINTER EXCEPTION` because the queue was actually empty... I'm assuming the queue is being emptied in the split second after entering the `if` statement. So I think I need the "Receiver" to have priority access to the `queue`?

Comment: Also very rarely... the program will run perfectly... its very confusing.

Comment: @Giri can't you have that variable updated from another place than the `Sender` class?

Comment: @fge You were right! I changed my program to update this variable in the "Receiver" thread and removed all instances where I updated it in the "Sender" thread. The program appears to be working now. Sorry for getting back to you so late. I had to go to uni.. Thank you so much for your help! It's amazing that you were able to diagnose the problem without even seeing a line of my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare a `BlockingQueue` in the receiver so that it can use the `take` method; the sender can still use a `Queue` declaration with its `offer` method, but you'll need to declare a `BlockingQueue` if you want to use the `offer(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method.

Most of the `BlockingQueue` implementations are actually lock-free, meaning that one thread can add to it while another simultaneously thread takes from it (lock-free implementations are usually more scalable than implementations that use locks).  Regardless of the implementation, the `BlockingQueue` is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage is that a BlockingQueue provides a correct, thread-safe implementation. This runtime implementation developed, reviewed, and maintained by concurrency experts.

A blocking queue is a queue that blocks when you try to dequeue from it and the queue is empty, or if you try to enqueue items to it and the queue is already full. A thread trying to dequeue from an empty queue is blocked until some other thread inserts an item into the queue. A thread trying to enqueue an item in a full queue is blocked until some other thread makes space in the queue, either by dequeuing one or more items or clearing the queue completely.